# Unreadable character in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need help in this.

When I query data from SSMS, I am getting weird character as shown in picture.

[image]

I have tried this SQL command, but it does not help. The desired result should be 1D or 1M or 1W.

```
CONVERT(varchar(50),[Date Formula 1]) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS [Date Fromula 1]
```

Comment: Unprintable characters aren't going to change when you change the collation. They are unprintable.

Comment: I hope, by the way, that `Date Formula 1` isn't an attempt to convert toe `timestamp` (`rowversion`) column to some kind of consumable value. A `rowversion` isn't a date and time, nor a readable text string.

Comment: it is not going to be timestamp. It is suppose to be 1D/1M/1W

Comment: Then I would suggest looking at what ever process is inserting/updating the column, and the process clearly isn't working.

Comment: What is your default collation in the database ? `SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));  `

Comment: You can do `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)` to see the code point of the character, which may give some clue as to what's being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

It is not due to SSMS. It is due to the way data is stored.

Originally, when the data came as 1D/1M/1W, it did not get stored due to one of the reasons:

- the default collation of the database did not support, ASCII characters like D/M/W characters
- If the default collation is non-ASCII and the column datatype is not NVARCHAR or NCHAR
  and datatype you did not insert with N'1M', N'1D', N'1W' i.e., with N prefix

```sql
INSERT INTO TableName(DateFormula) VALUES (N'1M'),(N'1D'), (N'1W')
```

- There is some issue in the Data access layer, where the data is not properly being passed to database

**What can you do now?**
The data is lost while insertion. No way to recover it. Better re-insert the data with proper unicode datatype or with proper collation defined for the column.

Comment: I see this all the time at my place where people import flat files that are encoded in UTF-8 through SSIS but don't change the encoding.  Just one common example causing this issue.

Comment: @Bee_Riii, agree with you. We need to be very careful with encoding of data throughout.